# Changing upper to lower and lower to upper

Tags: c, tolower, toupper

I am new in c programming. I would like to ask if this function is ok, 
because I don't know how to check this in `main`.

```
char uppertolowertoupper(char ch)
{

    if (ch>='A' && ch<='Z')
    {
        ch=tolower(ch);

        return ch;
    }
    else if (ch>='a' && ch<='a')
    {
        ch=toupper(ch);
        return ch;
    }
```

Comment: Call it in mains like this: `char uppertolowertoupper('f');`

Comment: In the else if, you probably want to compare it to 'z' and not 'a' twice

Comment: @karma_geek i have fix twice 'a' there in else  , but when i insert your call into main , it saying "expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'f'

Answer (score 2):

It may appear to work for you, but it could certainly be improved.

- Firstly, it's incomplete. You're missing a bracket (and a `return statement`) at the end.
- Next, not all C implementations use ASCII. If you were to use this code on systems where EBCDIC is the character set, you'd find that `ch>='a' && ch<='z'` includes more than just alphabet characters, and similar for `ch>='A' && ch<='Z'`... I suggest using `isupper` and `islower` instead.
- Finally, `tolower` and `toupper` expect arguments that are of type `int`. Your `char` arguments will be converted to `int` but there's more to it than that... The arguments are supposed to be either `unsigned char` values or `EOF`. Anything else is undefined behaviour, meaning any signed character values you pass to these functions might cause segfaults (e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877048/tolower-and-toupper-arent-working)). I recommend changing this function so that it accepts an `unsigned char` argument (instead of a `char` argument) and returns an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

An error (probably a typo):

```
    else if (ch>='a' && ch<='a')
```

This should have been:

```
    else if (ch>='a' && ch<='z')
```

Secondly, to call the function in main, something like this should suffice:

```
char ch;
ch=uppertolowertoupper('c');
printf("%c",ch);
```

The above works only if you have declared or defined the function before `main`.

**Declared** before main:

```
char uppertolowertoupper(char);
int main()
{

    char ch;
    ch=uppertolowertoupper('c');
    printf("%c",ch);

}
char uppertolowertoupper(char ch)
{
  // your function
}
```

**Defined** before main:

```
char uppertolowertoupper(char ch)
{

if (ch>='A' && ch<='Z')
{
ch=tolower(ch);

return ch;
}
else if (ch>='a' && ch<='z')
{
ch=toupper(ch);
return ch;
}
}
int main(){

 char ch;
 ch=uppertolowertoupper('c');
 printf("%c",ch);
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char uppertolowertoupper(char ch){
    if (ch>='A' && ch<='Z'){//if(isupper(ch)){
        ch=tolower(ch);
        return ch;
    } else if (ch>='a' && ch<='z'){//if(islower(ch)){
        ch=toupper(ch);
        return ch;
    }
}

int main(void){
    char test[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstrvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.?!";
    puts(test);
    for(char *p = test; *p ; ++p)
        putchar(uppertolowertoupper(*p));
    return 0;
}
```